# How does one export and then import an exact copy of a java project jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have tried various things starting with Java Maven project to get a jar which when imported looks exactly like the original but I have found that I can't for example get the src/main/resources folder to appear in the imported project. The goal is simple: so that on the new machine for example that the project can be run and worked on just like the original. Not sure what I am missing. I have tried importing existing project from archive which seems like it should work. On the original machine I select all files and folders but this still leaves out some things. I have tried to create an empty folder in Eclipse but this can't be done and various permutations.

Comment: Have you considered to export it into git repo instead?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Are you trying to copy and paste an eclipse project?

Comment: snickers: I am exporting a java project to a jar and then importing it to another Eclipse instance (in fact on another machine). The imported project does not look exactly like the project on the original machine.

Answer (score 0):

A jar file usually contains compiled code and whatever else you drop in there which in turn enables you to run the code.

An eclipse, maven, intellij, ... project structure may be completely different.  In the end a transformation will happen from that project structure to the jar content structure.  In the case of Maven this will not be the same as the project structure.

The intent of a jar is running the compiled code, an intent of a project structure is to edit the source code.

If you want to copy an eclipse workspace to work on then do so.  Copy the workspace folder.

Comment: I think that makes sense. But: 1. I have imported jars that apparently were completely functional projects once imported (Eclipse to Eclipse) so how was the original project saved and 2. If I copy the workspace folder, how will I then be able to import it to another Eclipse instance on another machine?

Comment: 1. You can export a project in eclipse as an archive. 2. I think you'd need the same workspace root and a similar eclipse setup.

Answer (score 0):

user392486 basically showed what to do. The key is to export the file not as a jar but as a zip and the import it as an existing project which has an archive option. that works just as one would want, an identical project. how i could not already know this is beyond me...